# Como puedo multiplicar dos Columnas varchar y sacarlo en campo?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Por favor si me pueden ayudar tengo que conseguir que al multiplicar dos columnas varchar  y sacarlas en un campo aparte ,
E intentado con convert y con cast pero no me funciona.

les dejo uno de los intentos , los campos son valor y cantidad

```
SELECT NumeroFactura,
        DetalleFacturas.CategoriaID,
        Productos.Nombre_Producto, 
        Valor, 
        Cantidad,  
        CONVERT( numeric ,valor )* CONVERT( numeric, Cantidad )    
FROM DetalleFacturas 
INNER JOIN Productos ON Productos.ProductoID = DetalleFacturas.ProductoID
```

Les agredeceria mucho su ayuda.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que no funciona? Tu numeric no está bien declarado. ¿Por qué guardas cantidades en columnas varchar?

Comment: No me permite desplegar el resultado de la multiplicación en un solo campo, puede ser con decimal o numeric , el valor que tienen como ejemplo : valor 9,5534 y cantidad 4,9  ,  es una base que ya esta cargada con varios datos no la cree yo por eso esta como varchar

Answer (score 0):

Aunque la base de datos está mal diseñada y **deberías ver la forma de modificarla cuanto antes**, lo que estás buscando es algo así:

```
SELECT NumeroFactura,
        DetalleFacturas.CategoriaID,
        Productos.Nombre_Producto, 
        Valor, 
        Cantidad,  
        CAST(valor as numeric) * CAST(Cantidad as numeric)
FROM DetalleFacturas 
INNER JOIN Productos ON Productos.ProductoID = DetalleFacturas.ProductoID
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la diferencia aparte de usar una función distinta que hace exactamente lo mismo?

Comment: Gracias por reponder , pero no me da errores me menciona que Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de 'CAST'; se esperaba 'AS'.

Comment: @JulioTobar tu comentario es para mi respuesta? La probé en mi gestor y funciona sin problemas...

Comment: @LuisCazares según yo está mal la estructura de su convert, y como desconozco convert decidí usar cast, ese sí lo uso a menudo...

Comment: @ Antonio Veneroso Contreras entonces mi sale este error --Error al convertir el tipo de datos varchar a numeric.-- es porque algun valor de estos campos esta mal ingresado y por eso no se multiplica o puede ser por algo mas ?

Comment: @AntonioVenerosoContreras La sintaxis es correcta tanto para `CAST` como para `CONVERT`. Por alguna extraña razón decidieron hacerla invertida (tal vez primero programaron CONVERT y luego programaron CAST con base en el estándar SQL). El problema estaba en los datos y era imposible saber cual era.

Answer (score 0):

Estuve revisando el porque no me transformaba de varchar a numeric o decimal,
y el motivo era porque no reconocía uno de los campos que estaba con coma y se guardaba como varchar  y la base por el idioma los esta reconociendo con puntos por esa razón no transformaba y me botaba ese error.

aquí les dejo como lo solucione si alguna vez a alguien le ayuda.

```
SELECT NumeroFactura,
        DetalleFacturas.CategoriaID,
        Productos.Nombre_Producto, 
        Valor, 
        Cantidad,  
       convert( decimal(18,2),(valor * convert (decimal(18,4),Replace(Cantidad,',','.'))))
FROM DetalleFacturas 
INNER JOIN Productos ON Productos.ProductoID = DetalleFacturas.ProductoID
```